# Does time exist outside of the universe's expansion?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime

Just been wondering if time can exist outside of the expansion of the universe?. Or does time expand at the same rate as the universe?.

Comment: If the universe is defined as all of space & time and its contents, what does "outside" it mean?

Comment: Outside the universe means whatever the universe itself is expanding into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the question is essentially "What is time?" or "How to measure time?"

Our best measures of time on earth are atomic clocks, which measure time by the interaction of a radiation field with the electronic state of an atom. This interaction can be used to gauge the frequency of the applied radiation field.

This interaction depends on a lot of things. For instance, there is the gravitational shift due to general relativity, such that the most sophisticated atomic clock experiments can *measure* a height difference by 20 centimeters or so.

So on the microscopic level, 'time' is always defined by the rate of the interaction between the elementary particles. Since all electromagnetic interactions, for instance, are mediated by photons propagating at the speed of light, all the arguments of Special Relativity apply. More difficult is the question of General Relativity, as we have no coherent theory at the microscopic level yet.

To come to your question: the notion of 'time' makes only sense if you have something that is dynamically evolving. So far, we assume that outside of the expanding universe ,there is just the vacuum. The only dynamics this vacuum possesses is to exhibit fluctuations, that is, the spontaneous creation of particle-antiparticle pairs and their subsequent annihilation. However,as I expect that these fluctuations appear on all energy scales that there is no characteristic 'time' scale associated with.